# How to Configure IBM Kubernetes CLI on Windows

Tags: windows, powershell, kubernetes, ibm-cloud

How to configure IBM kubernetes CLI?
I am receiving error when I export the environment variable of mycluster

`SET KUBECONFIG=C:\Users\myname\.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\mycluster\kube-config-hou02-mycluster.yml`

When I executed the command below,

`export KUBECONFIG=C:\users\myname\.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\mycluster\kube-config-hou02-mycluster.yml`

I receive error below.

```
export : The term 'export' is not recognized as the name of a cmdlet,
function, script file, or operable program. Check the spelling of the name,
or if a path was included, verify that the path is correct and try again.
At line:1 char:1
+ export KUBECONFIG=C:\users\myname\.bluemix\plugins\container-service ...
+ ~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (export:String) [], CommandNotF
   oundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Comment: Have you performed the required setup on Windows? https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/cli?topic=cloud-cli-ibmcloud-cli#idt-prereq

Comment: Can you post the error you are seeing when using the SET command?

Comment: Are you having issues still?

Answer (score 1):

When setting up the Kubernetes CLI, there are [special instructions for Windows environments](https://cloud.ibm.com/docs/containers?topic=containers-cs_cli_install#cs_cli_configure):

> Windows PowerShell users: Instead of copying and pasting the SET command from the output of ibmcloud ks cluster-config, you must set the KUBECONFIG environment variable by running, for example, $env:KUBECONFIG = "C:\Users\.bluemix\plugins\container-service\clusters\mycluster\kube-config-prod-dal10-mycluster.yml".

Comment: Thank you for quick response I can see Kebernetes master, coreDNS, metrics server  is running but when I opened thier url address I cant open them. What is the next step after this.

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Could you mark this answered and, if needed, open another question?

Comment: Yes its working.  Thanks a lot. I will continue working and reading document on blockchain development and ask another question if I'm stuck.

Answer (score 0):

We recently tried SETting Kubernetes environment variable on Windows 10 for a lab and it worked as expected. You can follow the step-by-step instructions [here](https://ibm-cloud.github.io/kubernetes-getting-started-lab/prepare-target.html)